# Reindexing issue in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, reindex

I added a column in `customer_grid_flat` table using UpgradeSchema.php . But each time I run the command `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` this column gets deleted.
I cannot figure out why this happen.Please help in this regard.
I attached below the `customer_eav_attribute` and `eav_attribute`.
[image]

[image]

Comment: What column you have added? Any customer attribute?

Comment: I added a column named  `customer_type`

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try using InstallData instead of Upgrade schema -

```
<?php 

namespace Namespace\Modulename\Setup; 

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactor
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;    

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }    

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {
         /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_type', [
            'type' => 'int',
            'label' => 'Customer Type',
            'input' => 'select',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 100,
            'position' => 100,
            'is_used_in_grid' => true,
            'system' => 0,
            'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
            'adminhtml_only'=>1,
            'default'=>0
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_type')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
        ]);

        $attribute->save();
    }
}
```

Then in your module in `customer_columns` tag in `customer_listing.xml` :

```
<column name="customer_type">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Type</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

Then create `app/etc/indexer.xml` :

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Indexer/etc/indexer.xsd">
    <indexer id="customer_grid">
        <fieldset name="customer">
            <field name="customer_type" xsi:type="filterable" dataType="int"/>
        </fieldset>
    </indexer>
</config>
```

Comment: Ok I will try and let you know

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **is_used_in_grid** as true while creating your customer attribute like below.

```
$customerSetup->addAttribute(
    Customer::ENTITY,
        'customer_type',
        [
            'type' =>'varchar',
            'label' => 'Customer Type',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'sort_order' => 101,
            'visiable' => true,
            'position' => 101,
            'system' =>  false,
            'unique' => true,
            'is_used_in_grid' => true,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
            'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
        ]
    );
```

**OR**

If you have already created this attribute and need to change the value then you can follow the below steps:

**Step 1:**

Goto **eav_attribute** table and search your attribute code **customer_type** in the column **attribute_code**. You will get the **attribute_id**.

**Step 2:**

Goto **customer_eav_attribute** table and search the row with **attribute_id** which you get from **step 1**.

**Step 3:**

Now update the columns **is_used_in_grid** , **is_visible_in_grid** , **is_filterable_in_grid** and **is_searchable_in_grid** to 1.

**Step 4:**

Flush the cache and run reindex and check.

Comment: It is already set as you said in db.

Comment: Can you take screenshot of the table and update to your question?

Answer (score 0):

This error mostly arise when your is_used_in_grid , is_visible_in_grid , is_filterable_in_grid and is_searchable_in_grid are not set to 1 in
customer_eav_attribute table.

After updating values please add code in the indexer.xml file.

Check code at https://github.com/rashigoyal14/main.git and download zip file named Createaccount.zip

Here telephone is the  name of the customer_entity mentioned in InstallData.php file.

Run command :
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean

Check your customer_grid_flat table. Your custom attribute must be there
Thanks